# Convertir una cadena hexadecimal a imagen con PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, imagen

Tengo una imagen en una base de datos **SQL** pero esta con formato hexadecimal, quiero mostrarla en una pagina **HTML** con **PHP**, pero no he podido.

La imagen es esta :

```
0x424D72320100000000003600000028000000BB0000008B00000001001800000000003C32010000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFEFEFEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFEFEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000FFFFFF000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFEFEFEFFFFFF000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000FFFFFF000000FFFFFF000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFF000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000FEFEFEFFFFFFFEFEFEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFF000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000FFFFFF000000FFFFFF000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFEFEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFEFEFFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000FFFFF
```

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? ¿Como conviertes la imagen a hexadecimal? ¿Cual es el formato de la imagen? ¿El campo de la DB donde guardas la imagen es lo suficientemente grande para que entre la cadena? A priori, la cadena no es una cadena hexadecimal válida.

Comment: no la canvierto, el campo en la base de datos es (image) cuando hago la consulta me muestra la cadena que coloque en la pregunta, y la cadena es mucho mas larga, no tengo mucha experiencia en este tema, y pues necesito hacer la consulta y colocar la imagen en un html.

Comment: Cuando pregunto como la conviertes, me refería a ¿como haces para leer la imagen y guardarla en la DB? Si la cadena es más grande puedes usar servicios como [`pastebin.com`](https://pastebin.com/) para compartirla en su totalidad. Por favor, intenta responder a las demás preguntas. Usa la opción de [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/284851/edit) y agrega dicha información en la pregunta.

Comment: Marcos muchas gracias, lo que pasa es que las imagenes ya estan ahi, soy nuevo en el trabajo y la base de datos ya lleva tiempo, y disculpame es mi pirmer post y no conozco muy bien el proceso completo... ya use paste bin... este es el link que me arrojo ... https://pastebin.com/j7k1ymFu

Answer (score 2):

Para convertir una imagen en hexadecimal a un formato jpg o png debes primero pasar la cadena de hexadecimal a string, luego puedes usar la función `imagecreatefromstring()` para convertir la cadena en imagen.

Para probar puedes convertir una imagen a cadena hexadecimal con ayuda de una pagina (por ejemplo [tomeko.net](https://tomeko.net/online_tools/file_to_hex.php?lang=en)).

Una vez obtenida la cadena se la coloca en una variable (`$data`) para que luego sea procesada y muestre la imagen:

```
<?php 

    $data="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";

function hexToStr($hex, $string=''){
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2)
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    return $string;
}

$im = imagecreatefromstring(hexToStr($data));
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else {
    echo 'Ocurrió un error.';
}
?>
```

En la linea `header('Content-Type: image/png');` se selecciona el formato de salida.

Como resultado de este ejemplo debería mostrarse la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probando con la cadena de la pregunta se obtiene lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, por el ejemplo, funciona.... la duda que me surgió, es que ahora no se si la cadena que tengo es hexadecimal, porque yo la veo muy diferente a la que me arroja tomeko.net, se supone que esa foto es la de un zapato.

Comment: @FRANCORALF  habría que verificar si es que la imagen se cargo correctamente o si el formato no era hexadecimal sino otro formato (que no creo por que en ese caso no retornaría nada), igual avisa cualquier duda.

Comment: voy a confirmar lo del formato y apenas tenga la noticia subiré el comentario, muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda......